# Unable to properly see grub when external monitor connected

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, multiple-monitors, dell

**Context**

I have a laptop Dell Latitude E6410 with a dual boot (MS Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04) install. I use grub v2.02 to select which OS to launch.

When I use my laptop only, everything works fine:
[image]

**Problem**

But when I connect an external screen (Dell 1909W) using VGA, the grub "appears" on the laptop monitor, but the rendering is totally blurred:
[image]
(I see a few 'one pixel wide' horizontal lines across the screen separated with large black lines.)

Once the OS launched (either Win7 or U18.04), everything is fine. Problem was the same with my prior Ubuntu 16.04 install.

**Question**

*How to make the grub menu appear 'normal' when the external monitor is connected?*

---

**`/etc/default/grub`**

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/default/grub` to your question and hopefully someone can spot the problem. I have never had one and always have an external HDMI TV plugged in.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks for the hint: it helped me solve this issue!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. I up-voted both your question and answer--nicely written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to solve this issue by **manually setting my monitor resolution in grub settings** (according to my actual screen resolution)

---

**1/ Manually define my laptop's monitor resolution in grub settings**
i.e uncomment (remove the `#` at the beginning of the line) and customize the last of following lines in `/etc/default/grub` as super user (`$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`). In this case, my monitors resolution is 1280x800:

```
# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x800
```

**2/ Update your grub configuration** based on new settings
i.e. — as explained in `/etc/default/grub`'s header — run following command:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```